How to adjust my code for a Zodiac sign identifier
My code run smoothly but my problem is that I only need to use array, for loop and if else. Only I don't know what to do, I'm stuck using that break in order for the program to run properly. What do I need to do?
Here is my code:
Console.WriteLine("ZODIAC SIGN");
Console.WriteLine("");

string[] zodiacsign = { "Aquarius", "Pisces", "Aries", "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", "Leo",          "Virgo", "Libra", "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn" };   

int[] signmonth = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 }; 
int[] signday = { 19, 18, 20, 19, 20, 20, 22, 22, 22, 21, 21, 21 }; 

Console.Write("Enter the month (1 to 12): ");
int month = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
Console.WriteLine("");

Console.Write("Enter the day: ");
int day = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
Console.WriteLine("");

string zodiacsignfinal = "";

for (int i = 0; i < zodiacsign.Length; i++)
{
int currentmonth = signmonth[i];
int currentday = signday[i];
int nextmonth = signmonth[(i + 1) % signmonth.Length]; 
int nextday = signday[(i + 1) % signday.Length]; 


if ((month == currentmonth && day >= currentday) || (month == nextmonth && day < nextday))
{
zodiacsignfinal = zodiacsign[i];
break;
}
}

if (zodiacsignfinal != "")
{
Console.WriteLine("Your zodiac sign is: " + zodiacsignfinal);
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("YOU ENTERED WRONG DATA");
}

Console.ReadLine();

The code run smoothly but my problem here is that I need to remove this break. What do I need to do in order to run this code without this break right here? We are tasked to create a code using for loop array and if else but without this break because this is not a part of our lesson.
if ((month == currentmonth && day >= currentday) || (month == nextmonth && day < nextday))
{
zodiacsignfinal = zodiacsign[i];
break;
}
}


Why do you need to remove the break? It's part of loops, and you're using a for loop. Are you overthinking things?

You need to learn indentation.

Does this answer your question? C# zodiac sign using array and if else statement

@ProgrammingLlama Using break was not part of our lesson so yeah im overthinking i dont know what code i need to put or replace inorder to for my code to work without that break

You could set i to a value where i >= zodiacsign.Length so that it doesn't continue the loop on the next iteration, and then you'd need to put the rest of the loop body in an else so that it doesn't run in that situation, but I'd just leave your code as is. Your teacher might be pleased that you've actually looked it up and learnt that break; exists, or that you already knew it.

Please note, that we can drop many thinds here: we don't want signmonth - 1, ..., 12, we don't want loop (signes are ordered) etc.
Let's extract a method for day and month input:
private static int ReadInteger(string title, Func<int, bool> validator) {
  while (true) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
      Console.Write(title);

    Console.WriteLine();

    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int value) && validator(value))
      return value;

    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect syntax. Please, try again.");
  }
}

The rest code can be
string[] zodiacsign = { 
  "Aquarius", "Pisces", "Aries", 
  "Taurus", "Gemini", "Cancer", 
  "Leo", "Virgo", "Libra", 
   "Scorpio", "Sagittarius", "Capricorn" 
};   

int[] signday = { 19, 18, 20, 19, 20, 20, 22, 22, 22, 21, 21, 21 }; 

int month = ReadInteger(
  "Enter the month (1 to 12): ", 
   m => m >= 1 && m <= 12);

int day = ReadInteger(
  "Enter the day:", 
   d => d >= 1 && d <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(2000, month)); // 2000 - let use 29 Feb

string zodiacsignfinal = "";

if (month >= 1 && month <= zodiacsign.Length) {
  if (day < signday[month - 1]) 
    zodiacsignfinal = zodiacsign[month - 1];
  else
    zodiacsignfinal = zodiacsign[month % zodiacsign.Length];
}

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(zodiacsignfinal)) 
  Console.WriteLine("YOU ENTERED WRONG DATA");
else
  Console.WriteLine($"Your zodiac sign is: {zodiacsignfinal}");

Please, fiddle yourself
